# Havin the problem with solving a nonlinear overdetermined system of equations

Tags: equation-solving

I am having a problem to solve a nonlinear overdetermined system of equations. According to one of the previous posts, I tried `NMinimize`, but it didn’t work. Shall I use any other method?
I will appreciate if somebody can give me some helps.
This is what I did:

```
eqn1=c[2]+a[2] Cosh[(20048005 d)/80227844]==9;
eqn11=5000 c[3]==21;
eqn2=1/400 (127-10 d)2 a[3]+(127/20-d/2) b[3]+c[3]==1330711849393/15087435934161;
eqn3=10627269662 b[3]==2478589 a[2] Sinh[(20048005 d)/80227844];
eqn4=6400000 a[3]==373 a[2] Cosh[(20048005 d)/80227844];
eqn5=(127/10-d) a[3]+b[3]==2321294/1027365129;
eqn6=4009601 (95161+1270 d (-9+c[2]))+20377872376 a[2] Sinh[(20048005 d)/80227844]==0;
```

I considered one of the equations as a constrain, also I know that $0<=d<=12.7$ and all unknown are Reals.

```
NMinimize[{eqn1,eqn11,eqn2,eqn3,eqn4,eqn5&&eqn6&&0<= d<= 12.7&&{a[2],c[2],a[3],b[3],c[3],d}∈Reals},{a[2],c[2],a[3],b[3],c[3],d}]
```

> ```
> NMinimize::nnum: The function value False is not a number at {d,a[2],a[3],b[3],c[2],c[3]} = {11.7176,0.212654,0.277116,0.987641,-0.332112,0.0042}. >>
> NMinimize::nnum: The function value False is not a number at {d,a[2],a[3],b[3],c[2],c[3]} = {11.7176,0.212654,0.277116,0.987641,-0.332112,0.0042}. >>
> NMinimize::nnum: The function value False is not a number at {d,a[2],a[3],b[3],c[2],c[3]} = {11.7176,0.212654,0.277116,0.987641,-0.332112,0.0042}. >>
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NMinimize` requires a function rather than a list of equations.

Let's take your equations and try three things.

1. Use `eqn11` to solve for `c3`. Replace `c3` with 21/5000 in the other equations.
2. Replace the equality in the remaining equations with a subtraction.

   ```
   eqn1 = c2 + a2 Cosh[(20048005 d)/80227844] - 9;

   eqn2 = 1/400 (127 - 10 d) 2 a3 + (127/20 - d/2) b3 + 21/5000 - 1330711849393/15087435934161;

   eqn3 = 10627269662 b3 - 2478589 a2 Sinh[(20048005 d)/80227844];

   eqn4 = 6400000 a3 - 373 a2 Cosh[(20048005 d)/80227844];

   eqn5 = (127/10 - d) a3 + b3 - 2321294/1027365129;

   eqn6 = 4009601 (95161 + 1270 d (-9 + c2)) + 20377872376 a2 Sinh[(20048005 d)/80227844] - 0;
   ```
3. Reformulate the `NMinimize` into a function which is the sum of the square of the difference between the left hand and right hand side of your equations.

   ```
   NMinimize[{
      eqn1^2 + eqn2^2 + eqn3^2 + eqn4^2 + eqn5^2 + eqn6^2,
      0 <= d <= 12.7 && {a2, c2, a3, b3, d} ∈ Reals
     },
     {a2, c2, a3, b3, d}]

   (* {31.4845, {a2 -> 0.844706, c2 -> -0.921421, a3 -> 0.000251246, b3 -> 0.000985941, d -> 9.25743}} *)
   ```

In the formulation I took the liberty of replacing `a[2]` with `a2`, `c[2]` with `c2`, etc., which I found easier to follow.

Comment: Thanks for your professional answer. But eqn1, eqn2 and eqn3 didn't satisfy?? Would you please give me some tips or comments about solving a nonlinear overdetermined system of equations. For example, What other methods do you recommend for solution such as FindFit[], NonlinearRegress[], etc.

Comment: With an overdetermined set of equations one should not expect all equations to evaluate to zero. They are minimized in a least square sense. If you go to the help page for [NMinimize](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NMinimize.html) and look at the top center, there is a pull down menu for Tutorials. There are four great tutorials there explaining the Mathematica optimizations that are available.